# Conditional expectation on functions of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value

Is the conditional expectation  $E[ f(X) \mid X]$ for a **bounded deterministic function** f on random variable X, always going to be $0$? Can someone please point out a reference or explain this?

Comment: What about $f \equiv 1$? Then, the answer is one.

Answer (score 0):

No clearly not. We can easily compute that
$$E[f(X) | X=x] = E[f(x) | X=x] = f(x)$$
and therefore
$$E[f(X) \:|\: X] = f(X)$$
We do however have, that 
$$Var(f(X) \: | \: X) = E[f(X)^2 | X] - E[f(X)|X]^2 = f(X)^2-f(X)^2 = 0$$